# Is there a benefit to wrapping a call in an array expression, only to immediately unpack it?

Tags: rust, wdk

A coworker sent me this interesting snippet from the [Windows Driver Kit (WDK) Rust samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-rust-driver-samples/blob/main/general/echo/kmdf/driver/DriverSync/src/device.rs#L45).

```rs
    let [()] = [unsafe {
        macros::call_unsafe_wdf_function_binding!(
            WdfDeviceInitSetPnpPowerEventCallbacks,
            device_init,
            &mut pnp_power_callbacks
        )
    }];
```

I can understand why one might want to do `let () =`  to assert at compile time that the `unsafe` block returns a unit type. I cannot, however, understand why these samples would wrap the result in an array expression, just to immediately unpack it. This is done with some frequency in the examples, leading me to believe that there must be some reason for it. However, the code seems to compile without doing this, and the doc examples [don't do it either](https://docs.rs/wdk-macros/latest/wdk_macros/macro.call_unsafe_wdf_function_binding.html).

Is there some reason why this might be necessary? My shot in the dark is that the array expression might provide some kind of compile-time safety guarantee w/ the `unsafe`, but I don't really know that for sure.

Comment: All I can imagine is that `let () = ...` gets picked up by Clippy, while `let [()] = [...]` doesn't. Not sure why they do any assignment at all instead of just calling the functions though.

Comment: If you need to assert that `macros::call_unsafe_wdf_function_binding` returns `()`, you can remove the array shenanigans and a swift `#[allow(clippy::let_unit_value)]` will make clippy shut up about it. But it does seem bizarre to me: `unsafe` already poses some requirements that are outside Rust's static analysis, and any half-way decent developer will use `#[must_use]` where appropriate (though things might be more complicated with a macro). Maybe there is some specific reason why such a pattern makes sense in this case, idk.